# Solving an initial value problem using Runge-Kuttas

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve the equation
[image]

Using Runge-Kutta methods, but the lack of y- values on the right hand side is confusing me. Any help would be much appreciated. My initial conditions are: dy/dx = 0 at x = 0 and y = 0 at x = 0

p = 1, l = 120, and E = 30,000

I am doing an iterative method from x = 0 to x = 120 with a step size of 10. These equations describe the deflection of a horizontal beam which is fixed at one and and has a point load at the tip. I know my deflection should be the greatest at the tip, but I am getting values that are much too big for the deflection. For this equation, the change in y is the deflection
[image]

I have gotten these equations for the first set of RKs, but I do not know which equations to use for the second set of RKs

Comment: Yes, they are constants. P = 1, l = 120, and E = 30,000

Comment: What can't you solve it analytically? Why do you need to solve it using Runge-Kutta?

Comment: I can check it using the analytical solution, but I must solve it numerically using runge-kuttas

Comment: Right, but I do not understand how to do so

Comment: Right, I did manage to get that far, i am confused as to how to apply RK to this set up though. I have only ever applied RK when the equation relies only on y

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert this to a system of first order equations.

We let $y_1 = y, y_2 = y'$, so we get:

- $y'_1 = y' = y_2$
- $y'_2 = y'' = -\dfrac{P}{E L} (L - x) = -\dfrac{1}{3600000} (120 - x)$

If you don't like this form, we can rewrite this as:

- $x' = y$
- $y' = -\dfrac{P}{E L} (L - x) = -\dfrac{1}{3600000} (120 - x)$

The initial conditions become:

- $x(0) = 0$
- $y(0) = 0$

**Update**

To Apply RK to a system of first order equations, we have:

- $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = f(t, x, y) = y, x(t_0) = x_0 = 0$
- $\dfrac{dy}{dt} = g(t, x, y) = -\dfrac{1}{3600000} (120 - x), y(t_0) = y_0 = 0$

We get the approximate solution $(x_n, y_n)$ at time $t_n, n = 1, 2, \ldots$ via the iteration of:

- $x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{h}{6}(r_{n1} + 2r_{n2} + 2r_{n3} + r_{n4})$
- $y_{n+1} = y_n + \frac{h}{6}(s_{n1} + 2s_{n2} + 2s_{n3} + s_{n4})$
- $r_{n1} = f(t_n, x_n, y_n)$
- $s_{n1} = g(t_n, x_n, y_n)$
- $r_{n2} = f(t_n + \frac{h}{2}, x_n + \frac{1}{2}h r_{n1}, y_n + \frac{1}{2}hs_{n1})$
- $s_{n2} = g(t_n + \frac{h}{2}, x_n + \frac{1}{2}h r_{n1}, y_n + \frac{1}{2}hs_{n1})$
- $r_{n3} = f(t_n + \frac{h}{2}, x_n + \frac{1}{2}h r_{n2}, y_n + \frac{1}{2}hs_{n2})$
- $s_{n3} = g(t_n + \frac{h}{2}, x_n + \frac{1}{2}h r_{n2}, y_n + \frac{1}{2}hs_{n2})$
- $r_{n4} = f(t_n + h,  x_n + hr_{n3}, y_n + hs_{n3})$
- $s_{n4} = g(t_n + h,  x_n + hr_{n3}, y_n + hs_{n3})$

Comment: Right, I did manage to get this far, i am confused as to how to apply RK to this set up though. I have only ever applied RK when the equation relies only on y

Comment: I am still confused on the relationship between the two equations. When I work it out I get values that do not make sense

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I added more explanation up top

Comment: Ahh, my apologies, I have added the calculations I am using and clarified the ones I do not understand

Comment: Is this enough information?

Comment: I see, thank you very much. I will use this in conjunction with the final y= equation to try again. Have an excellent night!

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to solve it analytically instead. We have
$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} = -k(l-x)$$
where $k = \dfrac{P}{EI}$. This gives us
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx} \right) = -k(l-x) \implies \dfrac{dy}{dx} = -klx + \dfrac{kx^2}2 + c_1 \implies y = \dfrac{kx^3}6 - \dfrac{klx^2}2 + c_1 x + c_2$$
At $x=0$, we have $y=0$ and $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0$. Hence, $c_1 = c_2 = 0$. The solution is
$$y(x) = \dfrac{kx^3}6 - \dfrac{klx^2}2$$